# devops workflow for C# windows desktop based apps

Tags: windows, deployment, automation, devops

What are the steps to implement DevOPs for a C# windows desktop based application.
What are the tools should be used to automate the manual process like testing, code review, code analysis, performance, build & release, deployment and change requests deployment

Answer (score 2):

That is a very general question. It relies on specific needs, budget considerations, technologies, company size, and more.
You can try all sort of free offering out there, just to experiment. Since you're working on Windows with C#, so you're already have strong connection to Microsoft, I would say check out Visual Studio Team Services, it's a cloud-based ALM/DevOps tool, free for up to 5-users team.

Comment: VSTS will defeat ! ;)